# Efficient algorithm for converting an array of depths into a Tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

I have a stored procedure that returns a flat list of names that are organized in a Tree.  To communicate who is the parent of whom there is a Depth value, so a result of 5 records (going up to 3 levels) looks like this:

```
Depth|Name
----------
    0|Ford
    1|Compact Cars
    2|Pinto
    1|Trucks
    2|H-Series
```

I am trying to construct a Tree out of this array by reading the depth values.  Is there some obvious algorithm for constructing a tree out of a sequence of data like this?  I'm adding the C# tag because I'm open to LINQy solutions to this problem though a generic Computer Science answer would be extremely helpful.

Here is my current attempt:

```
class Record
{
  public string Name{ get; set; }
  public List<Record> children { get; set; }
}

var previousLevel = 0;
var records = new List<Record>();

foreach (var thing in TreeFactory.fetch(dao))
{
  if(this.Depth == 0) {
    //Root node
  } else if(thing.Depth > previousLevel) {
    //A Child of the last added node
  } else if(thing.Depth < previousLevel) {
    //A Cousin of the last added node
  } else {
    //A Sibling of the of the last added node
  }
  previousLevel = this.Depth;
}
```

By "efficient" I'm talking List sizes up to 200,000 elements and trees that extend up to 100 levels, so really I'm just looking to for something that is easier to reason about.

Comment: My current code starts with a simple List<Record> where Record contains a List<Record> called Children.  I then keep a copy of the previous depth and do a test.  If the new Depth is equal to the previous it's a sibling, if it's greater then ti's a child and if it's less than it is a sibling of a parent of the most recently added.  I say "tries" because the code is getting rather messy.

Comment: Are the down votes for the vague nature of the question or the use of Ford cars as an example?

Comment: I guess the Pinto just never lived down the period when they used to go on fire easily.

Comment: When you say you need an efficient solution, how big is your data set?  Do you really have hundreds of thousands of items to add, or thousands of similar lists to populate, or did you just say it because "efficiency is always good".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is unneeded here. I believe the fastest way would be this:

```
public static TreeView TreeFromArray(Item[] arr)
{
    var tv = new TreeView();
    var parents = new TreeNodeCollection[arr.Length];
    parents[0] = tv.Nodes;

    foreach (var item in arr)
    {
        parents[item.Depth + 1] = parents[item.Depth].Add(item.Name).Nodes;
    }

    return tv;
}
```

Item is anything that has the Depth and Name information:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Depth;
    public string Name;
}
```

When using my own implementation of TreeNode, to simplify the procedure and strip it from unneeded functionalities that slow the whole thing down, and altering the method a little bit to suit thsoe changes, I came up with this:

**Classes:**

```
    public class Node
    {
        public string Name;
        public List<Node> Childs = new List<Node>();
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Depth;
        public string Name;
    }
```

**Implementation:**

```
    public static Node TreeFromArray(Item[] arr)
    {
        var tree = new Node();

        var parents = new Node[arr.Length];
        parents[0] = tree;

        foreach (var item in arr)
        {
            var curr = parents[item.Depth + 1] = new Node {Name = item.Name};
            parents[item.Depth].Childs.Add(curr);
        }

        return tree;
    }
```

**Results:**

> With the given data: 1,000,000 times in 900 milliseconds

Comment: @Servy I said **unneeded**, not needed.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Okay...then why add it?  I don't see any solutions using it, or even referencing it.

Comment: Mmm... Yeah, it's just the first thing that popped into my mind so I figured that it would be an obvious solution. It really is, indeed, unnecessary to mention.

Comment: The needed or unneeded nature of recursion aside, I'm setting out the implement this solution and I'm having a little trouble.  I think the foreach block needs a special case for the root node otherwise the first node is added a child to the parents[0]

Comment: @JasonSperske The idea is that the root of the tree will be the one to hold all zero-depths as childs. If you know that there will only be one zero-depth node (and is first), then you can set parents[0] to be it, instead of the new (and then useless) root note (or tree).

Comment: Implemented (with one slight change, the return line now reads, "return tree.Children;" and I've got to say, this is fast and easy to reason about.

Comment: @JasonSperske I'm glad you found it useful :)

Comment: Also I changed the "var parents = new Node[arr.Length];" to "var parents = new Node[arr.Length+1];" to handle the possibility that there are no children

Answer (score 1):

```
public void AddNode(Tree tree, Node nodeToAdd, int depth)
{
  //you might need to add a special case to handle adding the root node
  Node iterator = tree.RootNode;  
  for(int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
  {
    iterator = iterator.GetLastChild(); //I assume this method won't exist, but you'll know what to put here
  }

  iterator.AddChild(nodeToAdd);
}
```

It's kinda pseudocode-y.  It doesn't add error handling, and I pretend methods exist for sections of code I imagine you could figure out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

This array looks like a left-to-right "flattening" of an original tree structure. If it is safe to assume that, then the method is simple:

```
For each element in the array
   If the depth of the element is less than or equal to the "current node"
      traverse upwards to the parent until current depth = element depth -1
   Create a child node of the current node
   Traverse to that node as the new "current" node
```

Answer (score 1):

Ingredients:

1. A class that allows for child nodes.
2. A stack of this class type.
3. An array or list of this class type.
4. An int to store the current depth.
5. A local to hold our current item of interest.

Method.

1. Take your first item from the list. Put it in the stack. Store `0` as the current depth.
2. Take each remaining item from the list in turn. Look at its depth. If the depth is equal to or less than the current depth pop off (currentdepth - depth + 1) items from the stack, and the peek in the stack to get the new current item. Make our new item a child of the "current item", make it the current item, make its depth the current depth.

Bake in a compiler at 200°C or Gas-mark 6 for 300 milliseconds, or until golden brown.